# SQLAlchemy querying twice with a joined relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Basically, I'm running into a problem where SQLAlchemy (version 1.0.13) ends up querying the table that is supposed to be loaded as a join, separately, whenever I try to access any attribute of the other table through the `myrelationship` relationship.

The relationship is defined as follows:

```
myrelationship = db.relationship(
    'MyChild',
    uselist=False,
    viewonly=True,
    lazy='joined',
    foreign_keys=[whatever_id],
    primaryjoin=(whatever_id == MyChild.whatever_other_id) 
)
```

For the first query, for example `session.query(MyParent).filter(...).first()`, it does correctly query and retrieve all columns from both tables with a join, which is the intended behaviour.

The problem occurs when I try to do `myparent.meta.whatever` which makes SQLAlchemy query `MyChild` individually through a select instead of reusing the data that it got (and discarded) from the original query.

Can someone suggest what I've done wrong and why, despite actually doing the join on first load, it does not cache or use it anywhere and instead loads the second table again through a separate select?

Comment: After more research, found out that this actually answers it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898379/proper-way-to-prevent-sqlalchemy-from-re-running-queries-on-expired-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a commit in between fetching and reading the data that caused it to expire. Solved by using `expire_on_commit = False` for that session.